# Need I install oracle database for standby or only oracle software?

Tags: oracle, standby

I want to clarify what I need install for standby, I am confusing with this, in primary all fine, but for standby I dont know what I need install first? please explain simple, for primary I installed database without dbca, but for standby I dont know.

Comment: you need to install another database for standby, and then configure it for standby purposes against the primary site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a database (primary) already configured, running, etc, the steps are

On the primary

- Create a Backup Copy of the Primary Database Data Files Create a
- Control File for the Standby Database Create a Parameter File for the
- Standby Database Copy Files from the Primary System to the Standby
- System Set Up the Environment to Support the Standby Database

On the Standby

- Start the Physical Standby Database
- Verify the Physical Standby Database Is Performing Properly

In effect, the software plus the *instance*  (ie, the parameters etc needed to start an instance in nomount mode) are what is required on the standby node.  Then you will copy the datafiles from the primary to "flesh out" the database.

But all of this is documented really well in a step-by-step guide

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sbydb/creating-oracle-data-guard-physical-standby.html